# Help regarding logging in to chat.

Tags: support, chat

I can't seem to log into chat, and according to the Login help, it is because my HTTP cookies aren't enabled. Where can I find these cookies and how do I enable them? (Sounds like a stack overflow question!) Thanks.

Comment: I have been having much trouble with chat as well over the past couple of days, where it would constantly reload the page and even log me out. I believe other experienced something similar at some point. I was on an old computer, where these problems made me wait half the time I was trying to chat. I will see whether it still happens on this newer computer (I am somewhere else for a few days).

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed any of your browser's default settings?

Can you download a copy of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, or (wince) Opera and try that way?